# Angular JS collect all input values from a div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input

I am new to Angular JS, I created a div with input elements and I didn't use ng-model for input boxes.

```
<div class="row">
    <br>
    <div class="col-sm-10" id="rankingForm" >
        <p ng-repeat=" x in $ctrl.outputProductAttributeValueList">
             {{x}} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" />
        </p>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="$ctrl.onRankingFormSubmit()"> SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on submit button I have to access all input values .Please help me how to do that .. I tried as below.

```
angular.module("productList")
.component("productList",{
       templateUrl : "product-list/product-list.template.html",
        controller : ["$http" ,"$scope","$document",function productListController($http,$scope,$document){
            var self = this;

            self.outputProductAttributeValueList =[ "age", "gender","all"];

            self.onRankingFormSubmit = function () {
                var queryResult = $document[0].getElementById("rankingForm")
                console.log(queryResult);
                // HERE queryResult is printing how to proceed further
            };

        }]
    });
```

Now I want to collect all those input values dynamically created by ng-repeat. Please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: do you not need any validation or checking that the data is actually present?

Comment: NO need of any validation

Comment: All input fields are dynamically generating from server response. So How can I maintain all ng-model variables ?

Comment: you only need a `name` (unique identifier for field) and the value you wish to populate it with (if any)..

Comment: Tq @haxxxton.. I am trying that.

Comment: @VooraTarun I'm wondering, why don't you want to use ng-model. It's standard Angular approach - to work with model, not with DOM directly. Your current implementation eliminates all Angular's advantages and doesn't make any difference with old jQuery approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) is the standard approach for binding the view into the model instead of interacting directly with the DOM.

You can get all the inputs within the div `id="rankingForm"` you can do:

```
var inputs = $document[0]
    .getElementById('rankingForm')
    .getElementsByTagName('input');
```

Or by using [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
var inputs = $document[0].querySelectorAll('#rankingForm input');
```

Once you have the `inputs` than iterate over all of them to get the values.. Notice that I have added attribute `name` to the inputs:

**Code whitout `ngModel`**:

```js
angular
  .module('App', [])
  .controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$document', function ($scope, $document) {
    $scope.outputProductAttributeValueList = ['age', 'gender', 'all'];

    $scope.onRankingFormSubmit = function () {
      var inputs = $document[0].querySelectorAll('#rankingForm input');
      
      inputs.forEach(function(input) {
        console.log(input.name + ': ' + input.value);
      });
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="AppController" class="row">
  <br>
  <div class="col-sm-10" id="rankingForm" >
    <p ng-repeat="x in outputProductAttributeValueList">
      {{x}} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="{{x}}" />
    </p>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="onRankingFormSubmit()">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Code with `ngModel`**:

```js
angular
  .module('App', [])
  .controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$document', function ($scope, $document) {
    $scope.outputProductAttributeValueList = ['age', 'gender', 'all'];
    
    // Model inputs
    $scope.inputs = {};

    $scope.onRankingFormSubmit = function () {      
      $scope.outputProductAttributeValueList.forEach(function(input) {
        // Access to model inputs: $scope.inputs[input]
        console.log(input + ': ' + $scope.inputs[input]);
      });
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="AppController" class="row">
  <br>
  <div class="col-sm-10" id="rankingForm" >
    <p ng-repeat="x in outputProductAttributeValueList">
      {{x}} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" ng-model="inputs[x]" />
    </p>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="onRankingFormSubmit()">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>
</div>
```